# Use custom font awesome icons in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, font-awesome

I need to add custom font awesome icons in my iOS application. I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/spacedrabbit/StackScratchPad) and i am able to display font awesome icons, but i need to display custom font awesome icons. I have added its font file in code as well as info.plist, but still it is not displaying, instead "?" is appearing. Please suggest how i can display custom font awesome icons in my iOS app?

Here is my code

```
UIButton *tempBtn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[tempBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
tempBtn2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kCustomFontAwesomeFamilyName size:24.0];
[tempBtn2 setTitle:[NSString customFontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FIMinusCircle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
tempBtn2.frame = CGRectMake(120, 220, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:tempBtn2];
```

Comment: What Is this ?  [NSString customFontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FIMinusCircle] means whats that ?

Comment: I have created category where i created enum for all the font icon string there and rendering through this class method.

Comment: And what's the value of kCustomFontAwesomeFamilyName?